# IDE does not display all features in Android Studio after connected to GitHub

Tags: java, android, ide

Android Studio works fine for me if I create a local project and work on it for myself.

However, once I am connected to GitHub in Android Studio with Git as I am working on a project with a team, there are many problems that arise. All the rest of my teammates can work on the file fine, except me.

After starting Android Studio and connecting it to Git, it lacks all the core functionalities.

I can't even see the files that should be shown. 
Further, I couldn't even debug, there are errors with "Configure Android SDK". 
I tried downloading the Android SDK from online sources but they don't seem to work.

How can I solve this? I am running on Windows 10.

[Lack of "sync project with gradle files" function in the file menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebeJ5.png)

[Unable to view any project files in the project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HeKy.png)

[Problem with Android SDK not configured for module 'main' or corrupted and Migrate Project to Gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuULx.png)

Comment: Try doing a `git reset HEAD --hard` to clean your workspace then importing the project again using **File** | **New** | **Project from Existing Sources**.

Comment: @MTCoster Hi, may I know where to I apply this line of code "git reset HEAD --hard" ? 

I actually completely uninstalled android studio and reinstalled it again. But now I get the error " Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle Build System". I tried using all the solutions on other threads but it didn't work for me.

Comment: That's a shell command. If you're unfamiliar with using the `git` command directly, there may be a way to achieve the same result using your preferred GUI